# Istio Installation on Openshift

Tags: istio, openshift-origin

I have Installed Openshift Origin v3.9 which is running on AWS. I have tried installing Istio but some of the components won't start and am not able to get any documentation from online.

Whether we can install istio on oc v3.9? If yes, can you please share the documentation or steps to be followed to set it up.

**If my question is going to mark as duplicate, please answer the required things as i didn't find any answers/response for that**

Regards,

Comment: Not sure exactly what's the issue, maybe you could provide more information? One thing I can say while using istio with openshift, is that istio requires some priviledges that you can have with commands such as `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z istio-ingress-service-account -n istio-system` , `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z prometheus -n istio-system`, etc. (must be done for every service account created by istio)

Comment: Additionally may I suggest you to look at Maistra ( https://github.com/Maistra/istio-operator/ ) which is like a 'packaging' of istio tailored for openshift

Comment: @Joel I have given all privileges to the istio-system described in this blog(https://blog.openshift.com/evaluate-istio-openshift/) and I am getting the following error,

`2019-10-04T08:50:19.599192Z info validation Checking if istio-system/istio-galley is ready before registering webhook configuration`,
`2019-10-04T08:50:19.599199Z warn Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.`, 
`2019-10-04T08:50:19.599376Z fatal validation admission webhook ListenAndServeTLS failed: listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied`

Comment: Sometimes I am getting error like `Unable to fetch data from third party sites...`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Istio 1.1([Kubernetes 1.11+](https://archive.istio.io/v1.1/docs/setup/kubernetes/)) and Istio 1.2([Kuberntes 1.12+](https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/setup/kubernetes/)) required specific Kubernetes version as you see. But OCP v3.9 is using [Kubernetes 1.9](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/infrastructure_components/kubernetes_infrastructure.html#overview). So if you want to install Istio to OCP, you're required greater than or equal to OCPv3.11.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Okay Thanks Let me try with some higher versions.

Comment: Refer [OpenShift 3.11 - Installing Red Hat OpenShift Service Mesh](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/servicemesh-install/servicemesh-install.html) for Istio installation details.

Comment: Can u tell me how to upgrade oc v3.9 to 4.1 on aws